# are we charged for transformation instruction?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

are we charged for transformation instruction **(arrayUnion, arrayRemove, increment and serverTimestamp)** in firestore seperately along with one write operation?

Answer (score 1):

If you run code to write one document, it is billed as a single document write.  It doesn't matter what you specify in that write.  You can have any combination of FieldValue transforms or static field values.